# gganimate: change state_length in transition_manual

Tags: r, gganimate

I have this dummy data as example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

dummy <- data.frame(year = 2000:2022,
                    inside = rnorm(23),
                    x = 1, y = 1)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dummy,
             aes(x = x, y = y,
                 col = inside)) +
  transition_manual(year) +
  labs(title = "{current_frame}")
```

And I got:

[Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RlEN.gif)

What I'd like is to make the frames stay longer on the screen. Is there a way to do so when using `transition_manual`?

Thanks!

**NB**: This is a just a example for which `transition_states` would perfectly work (with `state_length` argument), but I have to use `transition_manual` for my real application.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the number of frames to slow down the speed:

```
panim <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dummy, aes(x = x, y = y, col = inside)) +
  transition_manual(year) +
  labs(title = "{current_frame}")
# Slow
animate(panim, nframes = 1000)
# Fast
animate(panim, nframes = 10)
```